# Android Studio: Need to add several edit text and an image to a file in external storage

Tags: android, arrays, file

I got a showroom application where the admin can add a car to his show. The design is ready. I need to store all the values given in a simple file where this file is going to be stored in the external storage of the device. This is my code:

I declared all the buttons and edit text:

```
public EditText make;
public EditText model;
public EditText year;
public EditText price;
public EditText trans;
public EditText color;
public Button addcar;
public Button uploadimg;
public Button cancel;

String[] toaddcar = {
        make.getText().toString(),
        model.getText().toString(),
        year.getText().toString(),
        price.getText().toString(),
        trans.getText().toString(),
        color.getText().toString()
};
public String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ListCars";
```

in the OnCreate Method i just add this  :

```
   make = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMake);
    model = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtModel);
    year = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtYear);
    price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
    trans = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTrans);
    color = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtColor);
    addcar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    uploadimg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

    File dir = new File(path);
    dir.mkdirs();
```

The i made this 2 methods :

```
   public void btnAdd(View view){
    File file = new File(path + "/SavedCars");
    String saveText = String.valueOf(toaddcar);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Save(file,saveText);

}
public static void Save(File file, String[] data) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    try
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
            {
                fos.write(data[i].getBytes());
                if (i < data.length-1)
                {
                    fos.write("\n".getBytes());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    finally
    {
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that i don't know how i can implement all the edittexts in the file that i want to save in and even to upload an image and save it to this file as well. If someone can help me i really appreaciate it :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a theoretical brief on what to read & how things will go.

In your Activity add a TabLayout and ViewPager to show tabs & it's contents. For each screen to display on tab click, create a Fragment.

Use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter to manage loading & displaying of Fragments.

[This](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout) is a very simple & good tutorial on it.